# Builder 2010 localization problems

Tags: localization, c++builder

I cannot localize a Builder C++ 2010 application.  Even following the directions in the help file.  Here is what I do:

1. create a VCL Forms application.
2. add the german language.
3. add the german translation of the form caption using the translator.
4. set my active language preference to german (project->language->set active...).
5. build and run and I still get the english form caption. There is no xxx.deu file created.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps look simple and correct in general, but there are two possible missed steps

1. create a VCL Forms application.
2. add the german language.
3. add the german translation of the form caption using the translator.
4. **Save Translation in Translation Editor.**
5. set my active language preference to german (project->language->set active...).
6. build and run and I still get the english form caption. There is no xxx.deu file created.
7. **Build All projects, not parent only. Both of project - main and localized must built without errors.**

Comment: Here is my working solution, very close to yours:
Ok, I got it working, here are the steps:

1 . turn on generate drc files in build options
2. goto project->languages->add and add the languages you want
3. right click on main project and add dependencies
4. do your translations
5. set active language in project->languages
5. compile and run

That should do it.

P.S. Do not call your program Library, this is a keyword and will fail builds.

Comment: Now, how do you add a stringtable resource to a c++ builder app?  I last used Builder 6 and it had a resource editor built in, I cannot find one in 2010.